# bat file string comparison working unexpectedly

Tags: batch-file

Why, in a Windows 7 command window, does the string comparison

```
  if "-e" geq "d" echo yes
```

echo `yes`?  It seems any number of leading hyphens in the left string argument are ignored.

My underlying need is an answer providing a reliable way to lexicographically compare two strings for magnitude.

Comment: You can't do an arithmetic compare on a string!

Comment: I thought the double quotes would make it a lexicographic comparison.  My understanding is the "if" comparison operators understand and will compare strings, given both arguments are enclosed in double quotes.  And indeed I've found that to work as expected, except for this hyphen case I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Discussion document

(Not an answer, but comments can't fulfill the task)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (
"e d TRUE"
"d e FALSE"
"-e d FALSE"
"-d e FALSE"
"e -d TRUE"
"d -e TRUE"
"-e -d TRUE"
"-d -e FALSE"
"qe qd TRUE"
"qd qe FALSE"
"q-e qd FALSE"
"q-d qe FALSE"
"qe q-d TRUE"
"qd q-e TRUE"
"q-e q-d TRUE"
"q-d q-e FALSE"
"aaa-bbb aaabbb FALSE"
"7-2 72 FALSE"
"72 7-2 TRUE"
 ) DO CALL :strcmp %%~a&CALL :strcmp2 %%~a
GOTO :EOF

:strcmp2
SET "p1=%1"
SET "p2=%2"
CALL :strcmp %p1:-=% %p2:-=% 
GOTO :eof

:strcmp
IF "%1" geq "%2" (ECHO %1 geq %2 TRUE  expected %3) ELSE (ECHO %1 geq %2 FALSE expected %3)
GOTO :eof
```

The above demo shows that OP's observation appears quite valid.

The strings in the `for` are supplied to the two subroutines; the first performing the comparison with the expected result and the second with the same arguments, but with all `-` removed and no comment as to the expected result.

The results for (*sic*) against (*processed*) are consistent, showing that the `-` appears to be ignored - and not only if it appears first **with one glaring exception**

The exception is the very last example. "72" geq? "7-2" returns "false" where "true" is logical. If the comparison is strictly alphabetic, then `2` is greater than `-` hence "true". If the `-` is ignored, then `72` and `72` are the same, hence "true". Even if the calculation `72 geq 5` was made, the result would be "true".

So what's the deal? `-` is not simply bizarrely assigned a >`z` collating value, or `-e` would be > `d`.

I wonder whether the `-` is ignored, but `72` is a shorter string than `7-2` is why this comparison returns "false".

More eyes needed on this, I believe. Yet another entry for the quirks book...

Comment: According to `if /?`, "if both string1 and
string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are
converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed." Is it possible that arithmetic operators are considered numeric digits (even though they aren't)?

Comment: @SomethingDark : quite possible - a `-` in a non-initial position may be `15` say, so `7-2` would be 7*100+15*10+2 hence greater than `72`

Comment: Aren't spaces ignored too for string comparisons? I think spaces and hyphens (and some other characters too?) are considered as a kind of word separators, which are ignored for comparing and sorting...

Comment: @aschipfl : `if "big deal" geq "big deal" echo yes` appears to make the comparison as expected, where a space is replaced by any character intriguingly, given the above, including `-` as an ordinary character.